# Guid Collision C#

Tags: c#, guid

Recently, we have implemented Guid in our Cash Disbursement process. In only ten days we have at-least a dozen cases about Guid collision. 
Please advise why different terminals on different locations are generating same guid and how to avoid guid collision.

Please find below our class that is generating Guid

```
public class Cash
{
    public Cash() 
    {
         Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the actual problem, but it dovetails with a Tech Talk within our company I've been prepping for.  Here's your code:

```
public class Cash
{
    public Cash() 
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

... there's a fundamental problem with this class: it's not encapsulated.  In short, the 'Id' property has a public setter - which means that any code using an instance of the 'Cash' class could manipulate its Id property.

So my guess is one of the two following:

1. An instance is being copied/referenced, and the copy naturally has the same
   Id property as the original.
2. Code somewhere within the system is messing with the Id property and resetting it to something else.

Even if the Lack-Of-Encapsulation isn't the cause of this specific problem, I'd *highly* recommend you change that line to:

```
public Guid Id { get; private set; }
```

... or ...

```
private Guid id;
public Id { get { return this.id } }
```

Anyways, as a couple people have posted, it's pretty much impossible to generate a full duplicate GUID.  So I'd suspect something like what I've posted above is what's actually causing the problem.

Comment: These Duplicate are coming to Server from different Terminal / devices located in different places. Each and every device is generating Guid in total isolation.

Comment: @Akhter You've confirmed that duplicates have come from separate terminals? Or are you just assuming?

Comment: being `Cash` a class (reference type) and not a struct, and not having any `Clone` or similar method, it quite hard to imagine that a copy is created around the program without some programmer wrote and used a method `CloneCash`

Comment: @Akhter then you have some other code that is assigning the wrong values, possibly setting the same value to multiple objects. Instead of looking for ghosts in a demonstrably safe function, post the *rest* of the code

Comment: You kind of need to have a public setter for Id if you want to work with EntityFramework.

Comment: @Akhter demonstrably safe means it's already run billions of times without issues

Comment: @JoePhillips we are confirm that these guid are coming from different terminals located in different location

Comment: @Akhter so which .NET version are you running your terminals on?

Comment: @Evk .NET Version 4.5

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Actually Entity Framework will still work so long as you have an empty constructor and explicitly define a setter on a property. The accessibility of either doesn't matter (both can be set to `private` and EF will still operate as expected)